# how to store a last 5days value in database?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table in my database
Table1 and Table2.Every day i update Table1 at midnight depending on a score value stored in Table2.

### The structure of both the table is like.

### id | score

But now i want to update a Table1 depending on score value stored in Table2 since from last 5 days or 30 days.

For example  the score value in Table2 since from last 5 days is:

day1+day2+day3+day4+day5

2   + 3  + 4  + 5   + 3    = 17.

Then in the midnight of day 5 database updates Table1 and increases score value of particular id to 17.

Next day while updating Table1 in midnight it should consider score value from day2.For example:

day2+day3+day4+day5+day6

3 + 4  + 5 +  3 + 9   =24 and so on...

Is it possible to calculate score value without creating column for each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of your question two cases are there :-

1. If only one entry is there in table2 every day then you don't need to create any column you can use rowid(as in oracle), only in case when no multiple entries are done in table2 in a day .
2. If multiple entries are there then you need to create only one column that is date column and can use sysdate-5 to do the calculation as of you require. You don't need to create column for each day.

Comment: I have to create one more column called "times". there i have to store value using time() am i right?

Comment: create a column entry_date in table2 as well as in table1 after creating it when any entry made in table2 the following date will be set in entry_date column then while inserting in table1 use the query :- insert into table1 (id,score,entry_date)               select id,sum(score) last_5days,sysdate from table2 where entry_date>=trunc(sysdate)-5 group by id

Comment: doing so will even help you to know when your table1 data is updated stated in entry_date column

Comment: Thanq for you explanation :-)